# Wordpress Show Featured Image on Main Page for Blog Snippet/Link

Tags: php, wordpress

I am looking to show the Wordpress featured images of blog posts alongside the snippets and titles of the blog posts (already there). We don't normally work in PHP so I'm having issues getting the images to show. This is for a client's website that turned out to be WAY more work than we anticipated. The code was originally pulling an image from a section they had titled 'Activities'. We moved away from that content and are using the 'Posts' section again for this.

The code for that area is below. Any help is GREATLY appreciated. Thanks

```
   <?php
   $args = array('post_type' => 'post','order'=> 'ASC', 'posts_per_page' =>2,'orderby' => 'date','order'=>'DESC');
       // The Query
       query_posts( $args );?>
       <ul>

        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php //$post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID () ); ?> 
        <?php /*$image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id(get_the_ID ());
              $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id,'post-thumb', true);*/
             ?>

      <li>
         <?php //if ( has_post_thumbnail() ){  ?>
         <?php if(get_field('show_this_activity_image_in_home_page')){?>
         <div class="actImg">

    <?php
            $attachment_id = get_field('show_this_activity_image_in_home_page');
                    $size = "post-thumb"; // (thumbnail, medium, large, full or custom size)
                    $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, $size );
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, the code looks like it is using Advanced Custom Fields which would have been returning the ID of a media item. As you have moved from a Custom Post Type to the native Posts these ACF values will no longer be available.

As you have setup the post data with `the_post();` you should be able to get the thumbnail url with `get_the_post_thumbnail_url();`

See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail_url/ for an explanation of this function.

Comment: I'll check that link out thanks so much for your help! Hope I can figure it out.